# When I try to play the game it gives me the CS0023 error "The ! operator cannot be applied to operand of type float"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BeatScroller : MonoBehaviour {

public float beatTempo;

public float hasStarted;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    beatTempo = beatTempo / 60f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    
    if(!hasStarted)
    {
        if(Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            hasStarted = true;
        }
    }else
    {
        transform.position -= new Vector3(0f, beatTempo * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code and I have the error at the line where it says `if (!hasStarted)`.

Comment: "float" is not "just the way to declare a variable" but it defines the *type* of the variable. And C# is very strict in its typing.

Answer (score 1):

The logical negate operator, `!`  can only be applied to booleans in C#. `hasStarted` is a float.

Try changing `public float hasStarted` to `public bool hasStarted`.

Answer (score 1):

In C# [logical negation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-) `!` can be applied only to [`bool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/bool) operands,  operands which can be [implicitly cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) to boolean or operands which has defined [custom overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) for `!` operator (neither of which applies to `float` type).

So in your case it makes sense to declare `hasStarted` as `bool`:

```
public bool hasStarted;
```